# Pepper robot doesn't move faster then the minimum speed

Tags: navigation, ros, pepper

we are currently working on robot Pepper, more specific we are trying to prepare Pepper as welcome manager. So when robot gets input from human to go to a certain location, he should start specific dialog for that location and moving to that location. For the navigation part I have set up a ROS Navigatoin stack and when I set a navigation goal for Pepper in Rviz he starts to go to the goal but very slowly, his speed never increases from the minimum speed that has been setup in local planner. I also made sure that there are no obstacles within 0.5 meter radius around the robot.

Here are my local planner parameters:

```
acc_lim_theta: 0.3 
acc_lim_x: 0.3 
acc_lim_y: 0.0
acc_lim_trans: 0.3
max_vel_theta: 0.5
min_vel_theta: 0.2
#max_rot_vel: 0.5 
#min_rot_vel: 0.1 

min_in_place_vel_theta: 0.2
max_vel_x: 0.7
min_vel_x: 0.1
max_vel_y: 0.0
min_vel_y: 0.0
max_vel_trans: 0.7 
min_vel_trans: 0.1 
xy_goal_tolerance: 0.3
yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.3 
latch_xy_goal_tolerance: true
clearing_rotation_allowed: false
penalize_negative_x: false 
oscillation_reset_dist: 0.03
sim_time: 1.2
holonomic_robot: true
meter_scoring: true
```

Do you maybe know what is causing the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you echo the cmd_vel that the local planner is outputting? Is it fixed at the minimum value? Or is it changing slightly around this (eg. 0.1 to 0.11)?

Comment: It is fixed at 0.1. Here is a link to picture of /cmd_vel topic: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4seooohavjftu7/WhatsApp%20Image%202020-08-27%20at%2022.31.51.jpeg?dl=0

Comment: Can you check if there's odometry information being properly published when Pepper moves? Should be on a topic like `odom`

Comment: It is published correctly. I can see robot moving in RVizu.

Comment: Is the velocity being correctly provided in the odometry message too? Could you try increasing the acceleration limit? Maybe this is stopping the velocity from increasing.